# Arbitrary precison floating types in .net. Any library that allows that?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I need to do maths on both floats and integers with much bigger accuracies and magnitudes than offered both by int/float/double in .net. Are there any libraries around that help with that? I recall there was something like that for c/c++.

Comment: The next version of the framework will ship with a "big integer" type that you can use in C#/VB/etc. It's pretty much the same big integer class that Iron Python uses, IIRC.

Comment: What is the name of the dll where that type is, in ironpython, so I can look there? Thanks

Comment: Ah, but is it just for integers? I'd need for floating point operations, mostly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodePlex comes to the rescue:

1.
Arbitrary length floating point library:
W3b.Sine
http://sine.codeplex.com/

2.
Arbitrary length integer library:
IntX
http://intx.codeplex.com/

3.
C# wrapper for well known GMP library:
http://gnumpnet.codeplex.com/

LP,
Dejan

Answer (score 2):

Yes and No. A simple internet search shows some interesting results. http://aaronfeng.blogspot.com/2006/05/net-biginteger-and-bigdecimal.html, for instance.

Take more time in phrasing the question for better answers.